# static files in Django does not upload when I changes the app name

Tags: python, css, django

I ran through weird issue. I have project for website. the project is still under developing process. I am using (Django 1.11). I decided to change one app named polls into ads. I have changed all related names in setting, manage, view, templates and all other related files. also I changed the table labels from the data base(mysql). then I run the server. on chrome and safari the html page is displayed but no css file is loaded. However, on fire fox is working fine. I tried to clear all data history but nothing has changed. I made sure from the setting and path inside setting file. finally, when I disable the ads blocker on chrome and safari (css, javascript, and images all are loaded) and the page displayed as it is supposed. My question here, why is this happen ( happened after I change the app name ) while before I changed the app name, the page is loaded with css and other file even though the add blockers are on. any explain or help to solve this problem

here is portion of the code from the html template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {% static 'ads/style/bootstrap_3.3.7_dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'ads/style/bootstrap_3.3.7_dist/css/bootstrap_theme.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'ads/style/first_page.css' %}">
```

here is the structure of the project

```
mysite
     mysite   
         init.py    
         settings.py    
         urls.py
         ......
     manage.py
     db.sqlite3


    ads
    static
        ads
           style
               first_page.css
               bootstrap_3.3.7_dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

           images
           javascript
```

here are portions of settings file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ads.apps.AdsConfig',
]


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

please note that when ever I run the server, there is no error shown and I get this message:

> [05/May/2018 08:08:51] "GET /ads/home_page/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16306

so every things seem fine

Comment: Are your static assets raising a 404? Can you turn on `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` and share a screenshot?

Comment: AdBlocker block anything which contains ad*, please consider changing the app url

Comment: may be this is the issue. I will change the name and see. thanks

Comment: ?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DEBUG

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out. However, my original question remains; is your FE making requests for static assets; and are they raising a 404? How are you serving your webapp - are you using the Django runserver? Can you share the 404 debug page that Django served you?

Comment: there is no error. the page is displayed correctly. just the css file is not loaded. when I run the console from the web browser. it whows me the file is blocked by a client.

Comment: Thank you BugHunter. I changed the app name and all files are loaded with no issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: also rtindu thank you for your response.